# Update specific slice of pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My highcharts pie data is as follows:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2
    }]
}]
```

I know I could update the `y value` of the first slice by doing:

```
var chart = $('#pie_chart').highcharts();
chart.series[0].data[0].update(100);
```

Or I could change all the data by using json:

```
chart.series[0].setData(json);
```

But how do I change the value for a specific slice based on it's name. For example, how do I change the `y value` for the Firefox slice if I don't know what order the slices are in (ie: I need to reference it by name)?

Comment: use `id` property for each point and the [get](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.get) method to get the point and then update it.

Comment: Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sh4Lsw12/)

Comment: Great thanks. That's just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate over data to find the appropriate index.

```
var series = [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 24.03,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2
    }]
}]
var i;
var idxFound = -1;
for (i = 0; i < series[0].data.length; i++) {
    if (series[0].data[i].name === 'Firefox') {
    idxFound = i;
    break;
  }
}
if (idxFound !== -1) {
    series[0].data[idxFound].y = 9;
    console.log(series[0].data[idxFound]); // { name: 'Firefox', y: 9 }
}
```

If jQuery is your thing, you can try the following, to have a newArray to store you user-agent name with the same index. Then you can look up in the newArray afterwards:

```
var newArray = $.map(series[0].data, function (obj, i) { return obj.name; });
var i = newArray.indexOf('Firefox');
series[0].data[i].y = 9;
console.log(series[0].data[i]); //  Object { name="Firefox",  y=9}
```

But it can be easily done without jQuery to make a newArray.